# How I can bind a List<KeyValuePair<MyClass2,int>> inside ObservableCollection<MyClass>?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class `Binding` with `List<KeyValuePair<BoardElement,int>>`:

```
public class Binding
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<BoardElement, int>> Outputs { get; set; }
}
```

And class `BoardElement` contains property `Name`:

```
public class BoardElement
{
    private string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have `ObservableCollection<Binding>`.

Now, I want `Binding` `Name` <- `BoardElement` <- `KeyValuePair` <- `Outputs`.

I try somthing like this

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Outputs.Key.Name}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedType}"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

But it doesn't work, because it needs something in the path here `Binding Outputs.?.Key.Name`.
It works only if I choose first element `Binding Outputs[0].Key.Name`, but I want to create a `TextBlock` for each `KeyValuePair` and bring a `Name` to them.

```
public ObservableCollection<Binding> B { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    var a = new Binding();
    
    a.Input = new BoardElement("D1");
    a.Outputs = new List<KeyValuePair<BoardElement, int>>();

    var c = new BoardElement("D2");
    a.Outputs.Add(new KeyValuePair<BoardElement, int>(c, 7));
    
    B = new ObservableCollection<Binding>();
    B.Add(a);
    
    ListOfBindngs.ItemsSource = B;
}
```

So I want to know how `Binding` colletions in another collection?
I can only choose by index ([0], [1], et cetera...) but I want to show them all

Comment: There's not enough code here, I think.  To what does `ListBox.ItemsSource` bind?  I would expect it to use the `ObservableCollection`.  Does it not?  If not, the item template should have it's own itemscollection, I think

Also, totally separate note:  I would not name your class "Binding".  Just to avoid confusion with the WPF `Binding` class...

Comment: it's really bad to name your viewmodel as `Binding`

Comment: , i am not asking how right name class, i ask another qus

Comment: Use a different name for your ViewModel class.  `Binding` is reserved by WPF.

Comment: @dovid: Vote to reopen and post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested list: list of `Binding` and each of them have a list of `KeyValuePair`.

### Option A, Nested ListBox:

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedType}" x:Name="ListOfBindngs" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding outputs}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key.Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

### Option B, Converter:

```
public class ConvertOutputs : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var list = (List<KeyValuePair<BoardElement, int>>)value;
        return string.Join(", ", list.Select(x => x.Key.Name));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedType}" x:Name="ListOfBindngs" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:ConvertOutputs x:Key="ConvertOutputs"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding outputs, Converter={StaticResource ConvertOutputs}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```